# Extracting DAU, MAU using BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to extract Firebase Analytics DAU and MAU using BigQuery. The query I'm using for daily users is below -

```
SELECT
  event_date AS day,
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS daily_visitors
FROM `XXXXXXX.analytics_153729556.events_20190825`
WHERE
  app_info.id = 'XXXXXXX'
AND
  event_name = 'user_engagement'
GROUP BY day;
```

I have a few questions I would love some help with.

1. There is a significant(2000+) difference between the value from the query result and the value the Firebase dashboard shows for the same date(s). Is there a specific reason for this or is my query just plain wrong?
2. There are instances where I see dates other than the actual table selected. Example, I see `20190502` in the results when `20190501` should be the only row (based on the table name). Is this possibly because the events being dumped into the table are for an app in a different timezone? If not, what else could be the reason behind this?
3. I also want to extract historical MAU and DAU data, and store it on MongoDB for any future requirements that may arise. Is there a specific way in which I can extract them - after overcoming the problem I'm facing, of course?

Comment: Your dashboard is probably using `event_timestamp`, which doesn't necessarily have to align with the table name.  The obvious case of this is a mobile app that is offline, will send its events to Firebase next time it connect to the internet (could be several days after the actual events).  These events will still have their `event_timestamp` as the actual time when they were logged, but they will be put in a table at a later date.  The `20190825` in this context is the date of the table, not necessarily the date of the events.

Comment: @rtenha In that case, should I be using `event_timestamp` to calculate daily unique users? I'm trying to calculate it with the `user_engagement` event. Also, how do I take care of the spill over of other days? I was thinking I'll just filter it out in the query  condition(`event_timestamp BETWEEN x AND x`) but is there a better way?

Comment: I would use `event_timestamp`, as it is when the user actually triggered the event.  You can just group by `date(event_timestamp) as event_date`.